# What happens to other threads when resource is locked in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, locking, thread-synchronization

I wonder what does other threads do when one thread locked a resource.
Can other threads do new tasks while they are waiting the lock to be released (like async programming) or they just doing nothing ?

C# code example:

```cs
lock (referenceType)
{
    // executing code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lock statement acquires the mutual-exclusion lock for a given object, executes a statement block, and then releases the lock. While a lock is held, the thread that holds the lock can again acquire and release the lock. `Any other thread is blocked from acquiring the lock and waits until the lock is released.`

This link is useful [lock statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock)

Comment: More to the point, the _only_ thing that other threads are blocked from doing is acquiring the same lock.